# MySQL: How to sort by column in ascending order, and show NULL at the end instead of the beginning?

Tags: sql, mysql

I know how to sort a result set:

```
SELECT * FROM `People` ORDER BY `LastName` ASC
```

However, the results that have an empty LastName show at the beginning. How do I sort in ascending order, and show the NULL results at the end instead of the beginning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    People
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN LastName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    LastName
```

You could also simply use

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    People
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(LastName, 'ZZZZZ')
```

Technically, the second version would fail if a person actually had a LastName in your DB of "ZZZZZZ".

NOTE: I'm sure it's just because you're giving an example, but I hope you're not using SELECT * in actual production code... :)

Comment: The CASE statement is redundant. You can just use `LastName IS NULL` instead.

Comment: I don't believe that is ANSI compliant. While the question does say MySQL, and the abbreviated syntax may work in MySQL I'd rather type a few extra characters and remain ANSI compliant.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT *, LastName IS NULL AS nullity 
    FROM `People` 
ORDER BY nullity ASC, `LastName` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `People` 
ORDER BY case when `LastName` is null then 1 else 0 end, 
    `LastName`
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it for you

```
select *, if(isnull(name), 1, 0) as is_name_null 
from names 
order by is_name_null asc, name asc
```